# Turn off whole document update in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I frequently write a meteor.update function like this:

```
Books.update(bookId, {"author": "George"});
```

Notice the mistake in my code: no `$set` operator - meteor will interpret the object argument as a whole document update, and replaces the entire book record with what I intended to be a modifier.

**Is there a way to turn off whole document updates in the server side?**

Note: one reason I have to write this modifier on the server side is that I can't write child array modifiers on the client side:

```
Books.udpate({
  _id: bookId,
  "readers._id": "123"
}, {
  $set: {
    "readers.$.name": "Ralph Reader"
  }
})
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to disable this type of functionality. What exactly do you mean with `I can't write child array modifiers on the client side`? What isn't working for you?

Comment: My example above fails with the following error: Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. [403].

Perhaps I should be filing that as a bug in Meteor.

Comment: The error complains about your selector. When you update/delete a document on the client, the selector must be specified only by the document's id. Now you're specifying it by it's id (which should be enough!) and it's attribute `readers._id`. Using the selector `{_id: bookId}` (or simply `bookId`) instead should work.

Comment: The issue is you can't use `$set: { "readers.$.name"` unless you specify the `readers._id` in the query.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve whole-document-updates in meteor on the client, it's by design.

This can only be done on the server, possibly through a method call.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Is there a way to make the server throw an error when you do whole document updates?

Comment: I indeed misread the question. So in that case, if you use simple-schema, it will not allow such mistakes even on the server, it always requires some operator, such as $set. I'll put this up as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I indeed misread the question initially.
If you want to prevent updates on whole documents, then in this case, if you may use **simple-schema**, which on top of adding schema to your documents, which is useful, will also not allow such whole-document-updates mistakes even on the server, it always requires some operator, such as `$set`.

https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema